# Comments to line number

Tags: feature-request, comments

If you have ever used code review tools like Crucible, Basecamp or Github - you know about their essential feature: being able to comment a specific line of code.

With the Stack Overflow engine, I don't see how it can be possibly done, as it implies "one question one answer" scheme, while for code review you often have several issues within even a small module. Several aspects, if you want. Like formatting, performance, naming, using deprecated or unsafe calls, code duplication or plain logic errors.

P.S.: maybe Code Review should use another engine, like sibling [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/), at least?

Comment: I know this is marked as duplicate, but c69 has a perfectly valid point here. For code review, we cannot use the existing stackoverflow engine.  It is cumbersome to do a code review in a question-answer format.